# Error Message "Could not convert to PDF" when trying to print a pdf from an HTTPS webpage

Tags: file, pdf, parameters, base64, http-post

When using the API call for 'https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit'. Here's the response

```
"success": false,
 "message": "Could not convert to PDF.",
 "request": {
  "time": "0",
  "users": [
   "akostin..."
  ],
  "params": {
   "printerid": [
    "530fcc06-0057-4154-f4a1-85219154aff1"
   ]
  },
  "user": "akostin..."
 },
 "errorCode": 403
```

What promblem could be?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same problem.

Comment: Could have helped if you had shared your CJT or request object to cloud print api! I doubt if you still have them :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply latest updates to your Windows, where driver for printer is installed. According discussions I found, it might help.